# How to compile java in Vim

Tags: java, vim

I can compile the same code in cmd, so my environment variables are right, but in Vim i get this:

```
error: file not found: Test.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options

shell returned 2
```

I'm using `:!javac Test.java` to compile.

This is my code:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: What does `:pwd` print?

Comment: Literally prints nothing.

Comment: Strange. What OS, what `vim` and how do you run `vim`?

Comment: Windows 10, gVim, I just search for vim in the taskbar and left click once.

Comment: Understood. Try to execute `:cd %:h` to set current directory to the directory of the current file, and then try to compile.

Comment: Worked perfectly! thank you very much! And every time I run will I have to run this command?

Comment: You may avoid running this command every session, I gonna write about it in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you got undesirable current directory (a.k.a. working directory) of your `vim` session. You can check it with `:pwd` and it should print the directory of the `Test.java` file.

There is `:cd {path}` command which changes current directory, and you can change the current directory to the directory of the current file with `:cd %:h`. After that `javac` should find the `Test.java` file.

There are several ways to avoid manually calling `:cd %:h` every session:

1. Run `gvim` via context menu (right click on a file, `Edit with Vim` or something like this), this way the current directory will be the directory of the opened file.
2. Run `gvim` from a terminal: `gvim Test.java`. As in previous suggestion the current directory will be the directory of the opened file.
3. Add the following line to your `.vimrc` / `_vimrc` file:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * cd %:h
```

With this command the `cd %:h` will be run automatically every time you open a file inside `gvim`.

Comment: @VítorAmesa - if you have not already seen it, take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Voting up and down (when you have sufficient reputation) and accepting answers to your questions are _always completely optional_ - but are helpful.